# How secure is the TAP Windows Adapter V9?

Tags: encryption, wifi, vpn

I use Cyberghost to browse the web on public wifi.  How secure is the network adapter?  Cyberghost uses OpenVPN which utilizes TAP Windows Adapter V9.

I am asking this, because I believe at the current public wifi I use.  The owner and employees are able to view my internet traffic.  Even while using Cyberghost.

Comment: @Xander: The question you linked is more focused on VPN provider privacy concerns, not "*current public wifi [...] owner and employees*" as the OP mentions. If a duplicate, this question seems closer to [Does a VPN hide what URLs I visit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/66380/32746). However, would I be the OP, I would most probably prefer to read [If I use a VPN, who will resolve my DNS requests?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/13900/32746) which, if the OP suspicions are founded, may give an answer to them...